# What is the correct font-size to get desired results?

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-size

I've read many articles, but I'm not quite sure what is correct today.  I want to set the font size properly, but I am not sure what to use.

I've seen body { font-size: 100% } and body {font-size: 62.5% }.   I have also read that the font-size should be px or not be px.

What would be the correct way to do it today?  If IE 6 [is outdated] and 7 are slowly becoming outdated, what would be the best way to set the font to cascade through the web site?

Comment: From a usability/accessibility point of view you should not use explicit pixel values (px or pt). This is because some people with poor vision may want to increase the font size used in their browser and if you've locked the font size to a specific pixel value then they can't do that.  http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Yes, I read about that.  Then I read the draw backs of using % as a base and the drawbacks of px as a base.  I wasn't quite sure what would have the fewer drawbacks to start as a base then to use em's to set the rest of the fonts. (I might be not understanding something here)

Comment: What specific drawbacks are you concerned about?

Comment: Browser defaults, mobile view, and stuff I don't possibly know about...

Comment: @Nanhydrin: Is there any way to size fonts sensibly relative to pictures without using px?  I would think that if one has a picture which is 160 pixels wide and would like some text to be roughly 3.5 lines long, setting size in terms of pixels would be much more reliable than any other unit.

Comment: @supercat: I'm not aware of any way to size text relative to pictures. Obviously setting specific pixel values would be more reliable for setting size but that's a desirable feature from the designer's point of view not the user's.

Comment: @Nanhydrin: I would think that having tables and things where pictures and captions maintain their proper relationship will enhance the user experience, compared with having text which ends up badly placed.  If a user needs to scale things, many newer browsers allow text and pictures to be scaled together; people who need to enlarge text to read it will often have to enlarge pictures as well, so having them tied together shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very much depending on your personal programming style and preference.

I for myself prefer to set the font-sizes in em. That gives me the advantage that I can adjust all font-sizes in the page, by changing one number in the body.

If you use a font size of 100% or 62.5% is also personal preference and depending on the layout. No one can tell you an optimal value, because no one knows what you personally like and want.

Comment: I was just more so concerned that people with browser defaults set to a higher than normal and if would matter what I set the base as.  I'm used to setting the font straight by pixel and I didn't really set a base in the past, mostly like it was font-size { 100% }.

Comment: the problem with % for the base size is, that it is then 100% of the browser default. If you really need a special base size than you can set your body in pixel and the rest relative to it in %.

Comment: Is there a difference between setting the base at 62.5% vs 10px?  And also, do you happen to know why people do 62.5%/20 or something to that degree?

Comment: You can't really say that 62.5% is really 10px. That depends on the browser default. 62.5%/20px is not for font-size. It's for the font shorthand and means font-size:62.5%; line-height:20px;

Comment: I would like an accurate font-size for a layout.  Based on default font-size for a browser would be 16px so 62.5% would be 10px.  I'm not sure if I should set the px for instance for a layout font (navigation) versus maybe just content on the page.  Its quite difficult to determine what to use versus what not to use.

Comment: That depends very much on your design. If you have for example your navigation implemented in a way that it don't grows in the same ratio as the user zooms in, then you should have your font-size for the nav fixed. If it grows in the same way then also that font-size should grow.

Comment: I've decided to just that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 62.5%, if you want your font-sizes to be relative (Useful for text zoom in FF and IE)

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.2em; /* this is 12pixel */
}
```

Why 62.5%? It's a value that works in all browsers

Comment: From what I read somewhere, 62.5% can faulted if someone sets their browser default size to a smaller or larger size.  This is why I'm not quite sure if I should use it.

Comment: @AllenTong This is what you want with 62.5%. It's for accessibility (a11y) Think of the disabled! They have big font-sizes as standard in there browsers. If you use `em` font-sizes (works with width and height, too). They will see larger fonts. If you use `px`font-sizes they will see always the same font. If you don't bother --> Don't use percentage at all stick with px

Answer (score 0):

This is less a question, but more general guidelines. This can also be applied to the line-height property, which can be pretty buggy in IE. As a UI developer, my workflow is as follows:

- Set a Pixel value on body, generally 12px, 14px, 16px, or 18px. (this will be your default). I would very much avoid using a percentage for your default font-size. I also generally set a percentage or EM based line-height on the body element for all text.
- Use EMs to define values for text. You may set your general paragraphs to 1.0em, and your first child to 1.25em to be slightly larger. Set your headers to appropriate sizes and so on. It really depends on the site you are working on, and your preference.

Remember, that with CSS once you set a height, it cascades down. If your default font-height is 12 px, and you set all of your divs to 1.33em, then set a sub element of your div to 1.25em, you are going to have a very strange font-size... It's not wrong by any means, but it's not best practice.

With a little practice this will keep you pretty fluid in knowing what your font-size is at any time, and works well across browsers.

Also with this practice, for the visually impaired who increase font-size, everything usually expands well, if you can imagine that all of your font-sizes would be percentage based off a default pixel size.

A good resource to follow for setting EMs after declaring a font-size on the body is [pxtoem.com](http://pxtoem.com/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Almost all browsers now do zooming instead of font size scaling so ems have no real advantage over pixels. EMs also have some really hard to work around disadvantages with the cascade that you've touched on above.